# loop and delay problem

Tags: android, loops, delay

I am trying to make a little application that simulates the dice. I want the picture of the dice side randomly change 6 times after clicking the button. It should randomly change 6 times with 0,3 second delay after every random change. The problem is that it changes always only one time not six times as wished. I guess it will be just some trivial mistake but I could not find the right answer anywhere on the web. Here is the code and I thank u all in advance:

```
   import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class OneDice extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.onedicelayout);


        final ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.OneDiceRollImage);
        final int[] arrayOfDices = {
                R.drawable.icon,
                R.drawable.icon2,
                R.drawable.icon3,
        };
        final Random rand = new Random();

        View.OnClickListener rollOneDiceListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                int j = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i<6; i++){
                    try {
                        j = rand.nextInt(3);
                        image.setImageResource(arrayOfDices[j]);
                        Thread.sleep(300);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Button oneDiceRollButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OneDiceRollButton);
        oneDiceRollButton.setOnClickListener(rollOneDiceListener);

    }

}
```

Comment: I've tried your code, outside of Android and the random number and wait work fine. I can only assume that the issue relates to the setImageResource method - maybe it's not getting enough time to update the image? Try adding a return, so that the loop waits for the method to complete before its next iteration.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I cannot use return in onClick();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onClick` method that circles through your dice images is a callback from the system.
Meaning that the UI thread which calls the callback will only operate again when the method returns. And the system is not recording what your are doing internally, but just taking the last state (i.e. the last selected image).

You can solve this with an `AsyncTask` where you have `doInBackground()`  (pseudo code):

```
for (int i = 0; i< 6 ; i++) {
   publishProgress(randomNumber);
   Thread.sleep(300);
}
```

And within `onProgressUpdate()` you can then display the image

Comment: I finally made it kinda work but now the random looks kind of strange (sometimes only two numbers exchange several times) and the delay is not as long as wished.and usually after starting the application when I press the button for the first time the image changes only once not as many times as wished

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it is a proper way or not but it did worked for me to show object moving step by step.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for(int i = 0;i<diceNum;i++){
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                            //do your Ui task here
                                                    }
                        });

                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(500);

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
//              }

                }
            }).start();
```