# Android: how to create delay in loop while still updating the UI

Tags: java, android, user-interface, loops, delay

This is my first post here so sorry if I don't format my question correctly.
I am developing my first Android app and it is a card game. I've developed the same card game in C# using visual studio. In C#, in order to simulate action and delay when dealing, etc, I slept the thread for a given amount of time, then called the method Application.DoEvents() which forced the UI to update. However, in java, I cannot seem to find an answer to this problem.

I'll post some code from my deal() method, which I need to delay so it looks like the cards are actually being dealt in a circle, and not all at once since the computer goes so fast:

private void dealHelper()
    {
        Hand pCards = Referee.getHumanHand();

```
    //show all cards in rotating order
    for(int i=0; i<CARD_COUNT; i++)
    {
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // load each card into their appropriate ImageViews and make visible //
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //human player
        LoadCard(playerCards.get(i), pCards.getCard(i));
        playerCards.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        playerCards.get(i).setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);

        // allow discarded cards to be clickable
        discardCardImages.get(i).setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);

        //computer 1
        computer1Cards.get(i).setImageResource(R.drawable.cardskin);
        computer1Cards.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //computer 2
        computer2Cards.get(i).setImageResource(R.drawable.cardskin);
        computer2Cards.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //computer 3
        computer3Cards.get(i).setImageResource(R.drawable.cardskin);
        computer3Cards.get(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

I need a slight delay of about 500ms between each card that is displayed on the screen to simulate action. I've searched and searched and haven't a solution that works (or I understand). Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank You,
Daniel

Answer (score 8):

Use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) with a [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) (which does one iteration of the loop in its run()) and `postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)` for the delay.  Count the iterations so you know when to stop and use the last one to `removeCallbacks()` and call a method to do whatever needs to be once the dealing is done.

---

Something like

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private int iLoopCount = 0;

private final Runnable rDealAndWait = new Runnable()
{
  public void run()
  {
    if (dealtAHand())
    {
      ++iLoopCount;
      mHandler.postAtTime(this, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + DEAL_DELAY);
    }
    else
    {
      doAfterAllHandsDealt();
    }
  }
};


private boolean dealtAHand()
{
  if (i == CARD_COUNT) return false;

  //human player
  LoadCard(playerCards.get(iLoopCount), pCards.getCard(i));
  playerCards.get(iLoopCount).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  playerCards.get(iLoopCount).setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);

  // etc

  return true;
}
```

And then in the onCreate or wherever

```
  dealtAHand();
  mHandler.postAtTime(rDealAndWait, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + DEAL_DELAY);
```

}

Comment: I've considered this solution, however I guess I didn't understand how it worked fully. When I tried to implement each card card deal into a Runnable, I get errors saying it can't access variables outside the method (such as i) and that 'i' isn't static? I need 'i' so the code knows which card to deal. I wasn't sure of a way around this.

Comment: You should be able to declare a `private int i` field in the surrounding class and use that in the runnable.

Comment: Another way would be to do whole for -loop in a separate thread. There you can sleep safely without blocking UI and shoot commands to update card visibilities. You just have to do it using `runOnUiThread`.

Comment: thanks for the tips @Ben and @harism, i'll try to implement your suggestions and let you know how it turns out!

Answer (score 0):

Try out `Thread.sleep(long millis)`.  You'll have to put it in a try/catch block.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works out for you from above solutions, then give a try to CountDownTimer here,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Answer (score 0):

please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15295980/1438915) it may help you. dont know its proper way or not but it worked for me very fine.

```
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for(int i = 0;i<diceNum;i++){
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                            //do your Ui task here
                            }
                        });

                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(500);

                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
              }
            }
```