# I need to load multiple images, one by one, at a set interval

Tags: android

It is a basic app where you click the shoot button when a picture appears. A picture appears once every 5 seconds. However, all of my images are loading at the same time using the code below.

I call loadImage to load an image, and then shootHandler to remove it after 5 seconds. I'm not sure if I need to use AsyncTask or something like that.

```
void run() {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
        loadImage(i);
        shootHandler(i);
    }
}

private void shootHandler(final int trialNumber) {

    loadImage(trialNumber);
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            resetButtons(trialNumber);
        }
    }, 5000);
}

private void loadImage(int trialNumber) {
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.red_btn).into(shoot);
    int resID = getApplication().getResources().getIdentifier(imageList[trialNumber].name, "drawable", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(resID).into(imageList[trialNumber].image);
}
```

Comment: All the images load at once because `loadImage(trialNumber);` is not within a Handler

Comment: Putting it inside a handler wouldn't make a difference because postDelayed() doesn't block the calling thread. I just tried delaying the image for 1 second and all the images still appear at the same time.

Comment: You said you wanted a delay, I'm not talking about the calling thread. You have a for-loop that is calling `loadImage` without waiting, thus "loading all images at once"

Comment: I know, but I created another handler for the image loading to display every 1000ms, but they still all execute before the 5000ms delay in shooterHandler()

Comment: That makes sense... If you have a 1 second interval on loading the images, then 5 images will be loaded before the 5 second interval happens to remove the first image.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to expect that `postDelayed` blocks the calling thread, but that is false.

If you want to call these one after another, each call should schedule the next one. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5996270/4388512

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't figure out what is your point but to load Images in the prettiest way you can use this:

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
    new Runnable(){
        int counter = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            counter++;
            if(counter == list.size()){
                return;
            }
            Picasso.with(context).load(list.get(counter - 1)).into(imageView);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    }.run();
```

Comment: make sure you add Picasso to your gradle as a dependency